# Add return type in def line?

Tags: python

I just saw this

```
def foo(x) -> 'int':
    return x*2

print(foo(3))  # >>> 6
```

and it is actually executable. But it will even allow if I wrote:

```
def foo(x) -> 'str':
    return x*2

print(foo(3)) # >>> 6
```

Is this a new function in Python that I have not heard of? To state the return type, like Java? But it is not enforcing somehow.

However, in python, there are standard ways to do the same work in python, for example, google style from pycharm integrated:

```
def foo(x):
    """

    Args:
        x: non-negative integer

    Returns: square of x

    """
    return x**2
```

Or javadoc style:

```
"""
This is a javadoc style.

@param param1: this is a first param
@param param2: this is a second param
@return: this is a description of what is returned
@raise keyError: raises an exception
"""
```

How do we manage the use of this from now on?

Please refer to where I can see this from the official documents.

Comment: 1. Relatively new. 2. Without external libraries like mypy it's for information only. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Comment: It's new as of Python 3.5. Check it out here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: @Chrispresso Very interesting, but some standard docstring will also specify the type of the variables and return value, if type hint is used, then how are we suppose to handle the docstring?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 I like docstrings still for giving an overview of a function/method but with type hints and things like `mypy` or `jedi` it is pretty useful and I expect more things to come with type hints